# Is there a shortcut for /cygdrive/

Tags: command-line, cygwin

Is there a shortcut for typing /cygdrive/ for every path? Is it possible to alias /cygdrive/ to /cd/ for example?

Comment: Does `ln -s cygdrive /cd` not work?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ man alias
NAME
     alias, unalias - create or remove a pseudonym  or  shorthand
     for a command or series of commands
```

They are used for commands only.

if you want to create a shortcut to /cygdrive i recommend using environment variables:
`export PROJECT_DIR=/cygdrive/c/path/to/project`
`export c_dir=/cygdrive/c`
`export d_dir=/cygdrive/d`

Put these into the .profile file under your home directory.
Usage:

```
cd $c_dir
cd $d_dir
cd $PROJECT_DIR
```

Comment: Although you can `alias c:='/cydrive/c'` too, it might have some unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 5):

You could use : `mount --change-cygdrive-prefix`

For example : `mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /` and `cd /c/` will change the working directory to `/cygdrive/c/`.

For permanent change (not session's change), you need to change the Windows registry.

Comment: There's no need to edit the registry. In Cygwin versions before 1.7, changing the prefix with the mount command automatically became permanent, by updating the relevant registry entry. In Cygwin 1.7, mount points are no longer stored in the registry but read from `/etc/fstab`. See the [user manual](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table) for the format of this.

Comment: This is the correct solution, supported by Cygwin, as the manual for the Cygwin [mount](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount) command shows.

Comment: I just added this to my `.bashrc` and it works great, thanks!

Comment: If I put this solution in my `.bashrc` or the `.bash_profile` either one  file `$HOME` ends up being incorrect and everything referencing it or `~` fail.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is create symbolic links in the Cygwin home for those directories that I go to regularly, for example:

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/code
```

Then `$ cd code` takes me where I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use tab completion? eg type `cd /cy` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it should hopefully complete to `/cygdrive/`

Comment: FYI zsh completion will expand `cd /cy/c` to `cd /cygdrive/c`, I think bash won't. Of course, zsh completion will do the whole path as abbreviations, e.g. `cd /cy/c/prog/mi/` [TAB] reliant on unique abbreviations of course.

Answer (score 1):

the following is a cygwin mount solution:

```
mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /
```

then instead of `cd /cygdrive/c`

```
cd /c
```

the earlier posts aliases are still useful for shortening "cd long-path" commands

Answer (score 1):

I found a more correct answer<sup>[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/how-do-i-get-rid-of-cygwins-cygdrive-prefix-in-all-paths)</sup> after I used the accepted one here and felt it was way to hacky to be correct given all the stuff it broke.

edit `/etc/fstab` the current version as of this time is

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

make it look like

```
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

and you are good to go, no hacks to replace stuff in `$PATH` or `$HOME` or anything else!